# Whatsapp Web in Lockdown Mode

Tags: safari, whatsapp.app, ventura

When turning on the Lockdown Mode feature, new in macOS Ventura, it seems some web applications are not working using Safari.

Especially, I saw that the Whatsapp Web application is not working. It's not showing the Login QR code at the beginning.

What's the specific feature that Lockdown Mode disabled, making this application not working? And, is it possible to turn it on (eg via the Develop menu of Safari), yet keeping the Lockdown Mode enabled? What are the approaches to debug this case?

Comment: Read https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT212650. Can you explain why you turned on Lockdown Mode?  Are you someone who "may be personally targeted by some of the most sophisticated digital threats"? If so, you shouldn't want to weaken its protections.

Comment: @Gilby Your questions and my personal reasons are irrelevant to the concrete question. I have my reasons to run Lockdown Mode, and wonder about some specific limit (from the link you referenced, that I read before), and whether it can be neutralized. In my opinion, it's sometimes ok to disable some protection, even for a short time, and still justify other protections.

Comment: @Gilby However, if there are other solutions to run WhatsApp without disabling Lockdown Mode, I'd also love to know, so we won't have to neutralize any protection. For example, I thought maybe WhatsApp is developed incorrectly, not considering this Mode, regardless of some dependence on a limited feature by Lockdown's